# Android app UI randomly gets stuck with click animations still working but onclicklisteners not getting triggered

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, freeze

In the app that I am currently working on there is a persisting bug that partly "freezes" the UI at seemingly random times:

The UI suddenly freezes while being in the foreground but all ui components (buttons, tabs, etc.) are still clickable. When I tap a component, the clicking animation gets triggered but the onClickListener behind it is not getting triggered. The component then will visually stay "clicked" and does not return to a state where it can be clicked it again. Scrolling in ScrollViews still works when the issue occurs.
So, the UI seems to be not completely frozen but it is basically unresponsive which forces the user to kill and reopen the app again.
Once the app is restarted everything works fine again.

The frequency of this bug appearing seems to differ between devices. It happens rarely(maybe once every few days) on a Samsung Galaxy S10 5G(Android 12) but multiple times an hour on a OnePlus 8T(also Android 12).

The currently targeted Android SDK is Android 12L (SDK 32) but the issue already persisted on Android 11 (SDK 30)

The app does not crash, so there is no crash report. The app basically keeps running until the user kills the app.
However, there has been an instance where I got the following ANR: (It is difficult to say if that ANR is directly caused by this issue or if it is a result of various things failing after this bug occurs.)

```
E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.myApp.debug (com.myApp.debug/com.myApp.View.MainScreen)
    PID: 11357
    Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Application does not have a focused window)
    Parent: com.myApp.debug/com.myApp.View.MainScreen
    Frozen: false
    Load: 8.0 / 8.88 / 9.36
    ----- Output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
    some avg10=0.08 avg60=0.02 avg300=0.18 total=25943745
    full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=4032128
    ----- End output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
```

I have spent many hours trying to get to root of this issue but couldn't find anything substantial that might be causing this problem. However, through reading countless posts on the internet I came up with a few possible causes for this issue:

possible Memory Leak??:
I have monitored the app's RAM and CPU usage in the Android Studio profiler... and while there are times the app is using quite a bit of RAM, the issue seems to also occur when the app does not use a lot of RAM at all. CPU usage is also usually around 5%

too many fragments??:
Multiple fragments get attached to a single main activity during runtime. Those fragments are either elements in a page or also used as full pages that get overlayed on top of the main activity. In case of going through a certain setup wizard there can be more than 10 Fragments displayed on top of the main activity.

too much load on main thread??:
The app does send frequent requests to devices via Bluetooth, Wifi or Cloud every few seconds, through which the views then get updated, but there does not seem to be a point where there would be extreme load on the main thread or backend threads that would cause the UI to freeze. The views usually get updated through receiving data from conflated channels which is then processed inside the view through comsumeEach methods.

Any experiences with similar issues or any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can try disabling the functions you think are the cause to see if it reappears. If it appears randomly I think it may come from the request you do every few seconds. Leave debug Log everywhere in your code to see what the last activity shows up before a freeze

Comment: I have actually found the issue but I didn't update this post yet, sorry. Yeah, I used exactly the same method as you just suggested and I found the code block that was causing the issue. I am still not sure what the issue was exactly but the code was merely updating some UI elements within a fragment (text colors, set Drawables, etc...) but seemingly not from the main thread??? The function that updates the UI elements was not specified to run on a specific thread. I then ran it in a MainScope.launch{} and this seemed to have fixed the issue.